# Função =VLOOKUP(MAX($B$5:$B$11);$A$5:$A$11;1;0) Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, funções

Estou usando a função:

=VLOOKUP(MAX($B$5:$B$11);$A$5:$A$11;1;0) na célula B23 no Excel 2010.

Resultado: #N/A!

Alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir minha fórmula?

Muito agradecido, 
Silvio.

[image: LAS Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1):

Você está procurando o valor máximo de **$B$5:$B$11** que é **118** na coluna **$A$5:$A$11** e retornando um valor da coluna A também, neste caso, não tem nada mesmo. A função não está encontrando nenhuma referência. 
O erro **#N/D** acontece quando o Excel não consegue encontrar o que você pediu

Não sei qual é a busca que quer fazer, mas é só adequar a função.

A seguir vai a estrutura dessa função:

> =VLOOKUP(valor_procurado,matriz_tabela,número_índice_coluna,procurar_intervalo
>
> valor_procurado: o valor a ser localizado na primeira coluna da matriz.
>
> matriz_tabela: a tabela de informações na qual os dados são procurados.
>
> índice_coluna: o número da coluna na matriz_tabela para a qual o                valor correspondente deve ser retornado.
>
> procurar_intervalo: é um valor lógico que especifica se deseja encontrar uma correspondência exata ou uma correspondência aproximada. Se VERDADEIRO ou não especificada, uma correspondência aproximada é retornada
>
> Fonte: https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/181213

Geralmente a **matriz_tabela** não é somente uma coluna, pois procuramos na primeira coluna, mas para retornar outra coluna mais a frente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, troque todos os ";" por '," para ver se funciona corretamente!

Amigo, fazendo uma correção, tente usar a função PROCV ao invés dessa que estas usando, acredito eu que seja questão de idioma! (por isso pedi para trocar os sinais!

Comment: Olá Jr, se eu troco por virgula, da um erro de fórmula matemática!
O meu excel é Japonês! Após iniciar a =VLOOKUP( uso o ctrl A aqui para forçar o aparecer do auxiliar de fórmula e automaticamente insere o ; .

Answer (score 0):

Ola Junior e Denis resolvemos o problema com esta formula:

=INDEX(A$4:A$11; MATCH(MAX(B5:B11); B$4:B$11; 0))

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335845/function-vlookupmaxb5b11a4b1111-excel-2010

Abraços e muito agradecido.